# Is there a way to prevent Markdown nesting abuse?

Tags: php, markdown

I'm using the PHP Markdown script available here: http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/

I noticed today that if someone posts a message containing text like:

`>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Hello World <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<`

...Xdebug will produce a fatal error due to in excess of 100 nested function calls. I then realized that pretty much any markdown syntax can be abused in this way - in many cases inadvertently.

I fixed the problem by replacing instances of `>>>>` with `>\>\>\>`, but that doesn't seem like an adequate solution at all.

Has anyone come across this? Is there a better PHP script for formatting Markdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Markdown the normal route is to make sure you have good HTML sanitization applied afterward, and then add hacks as necessary. For the `>>>>>` a simple hack would be:

```
preg_replace_callback("|>{5,}|", function($match) { 
    return preg_replace('|.|', '\>', $match[0]);
}, $input);
```

This adds a backslash to escape sequences of `>` that are five or more characters long.

Thankfully there are efforts to write more solid Markdown parsers. One such effort is Sundown, based on Upskirt, which is in C but has a PHP extension: https://github.com/chobie/php-sundown

Comment: Perhaps `/(\*|\_|\>|\ ){5,}/` to prevent nested bold, italic and blockquotes? Even that isn't a complete solution though.

Comment: Yes, a robust Markdown parser would be nice. It isn't the standard way of doing it, though. For now, in many languages, GIGO.

Comment: ...but using the one GitHub uses might fix it. If you can use PHP extensions this may be worth a look: https://github.com/chobie/php-sundown

Comment: That isn't helpful, applicative. This is a specific question, not a question about general troubleshooting strategies.